# Type Mismatch Error when selecting continuous cells to perform operations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` assigned to the button `Change Type in Bulk`, this `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` function throws a `Type Mismatch Error`.

### Logic of my code & how it went wrong

To explain what is `Change Type in Bulk`:

- `Change Type in Bulk` button calls the `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` macro function.
- `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` function call the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` function, which performs double click on every cell selected.
- `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` function changes the cell values alternatively from **"B&A"** to **"B"** to **"A"** to **""**, whenever you perform double click on the cells.

The `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` function throws a `Type Mismatch Error`, the error occurs in the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` function in the line

```
Elself target.Row > Range (Print_Something_Rg).Row And Len (Trim(target.Offset (, 1) .Value)) > 0 Then
```

whenever I **select continuous cells**, but there is no error when I **select cells separately** / **only select 1 cell**.

### Variables in my code

1. `Print_Something_Rg` is a defined range, referring to the cell **to the right of `Type`** in the picture, you can consider `Print_Something_Rg` as the start of different product codes.
2. `target` is the cells we selected (if you refer to the picture you can see cells being selected)

Example of selecting cells separately:

[image: This is allowed]

Example of selecting continuous cells:

[image]

### My code

```
Sub ChangeTypeByDoubleClick()
    Call Sheet5. Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick (Selection, False)
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim rg_block    As Range
    
    If target.Column = Range(Print_Something_Rg).Offset(, -1).Column And Len(Trim (Range(Print_Something_Rg).Offset(1).Value)) > 0 Then
        Cancel = TRUE
        If target.Row = Range(Print_Something_Rg).Row Then
            If Len (Trim(target.Offset(1, 1).Value)) > 0 Then
                Set rg_block = Range (target.Offset (1, 1), target.Offset (1, 1) . End (xlDown)).Offset(, -1)
                If target.Offset (1).Value = "" Then
                    rg_block.Value = "B & A"
                    Elself target.Offset (1).Value = "B & A" Then
                    rg_block.Value = "B"
                    Elself target.Offset(1).Value = "B" Then
                    rg_block.Value = "A"
                Else
                    rg_block.Value = ""
                End If
            End If
            Elself target.Row > Range (Print_Something_Rg).Row And Len (Trim(target.Offset (, 1) .Value)) > 0 Then
            If target.Value = "" Then
                target.Value =
                "B & A"
                Elself target.Value = "B & A" Then
                target.Value = "B"
                Elself target.Value = "B" Then
                target.Value = "A"
            Else
                target.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not exactly sure why would my code break when I select continuous cells, because the `Selection` should be a range already (so it shouldn't be wrong).

I have double checked the type of my code, and the type should be assigned properly. Considering it only breaks when I select continuous cells, my guess is that it has something to do with it - but I could not figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole approach is wrong. Usually, you create the procedure in a standard module. Then you call it where you need it, in this case, in the `BeforeDoubleClick` event procedure and in the `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick` procedure, where ever it is located. The procedure's signature could look like `Sub ChangeType(ByVal target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)` and the calls would look like `ChangeType Target, True` in the event procedure, and `ChangeType Target, False` in e.g. BigBen's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Target` is a multi-cell range, its `.Value` is a 2D array, which you can't call `Trim` or `Len` on.

Normally this situation wouldn't even arise since you can only double-click a single cell, but obviously your case is different.

Add a loop to `ChangeTypeByDoubleClick()`:

```
Sub ChangeTypeByDoubleClick()
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell in Selection
        Sheet5.Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick cell, False
    Next
End Sub
```

As noted in the comments though, it would be much better to move the procedure into a standard module, and call that procedure within the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` handler.